# Remove TFS GlobalList using TFS ExtendedClient API

Tags: c#, xml, tfs-2015

I tried to remove a GLOBALLIST from GLOBALLIST xml data and then tried to import the updated xml data to tfs server but **nothing get updated** using below line of code.[**no error is throwing**]

```
store.ImportGlobalLists(collectionGlobalListRoot.InnerXml);
```

**Note:** here **store** is `WorkItemStore` and `collectionGlobalListRoot` is the `XMLDocument` contains entire **updated globallist xml** of collection.

**Addition of GlobalList is working fine here.**

I am wondering do i have to use any different mechanism to destroy a globallist via API?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the normal flow of modify Global list is export the Global List XML, modify the XML and import it back.

> However, deleting a Global List is not possible. Because **the
>   Import/Export methods are set up in a way  that you can also add or
>   update** 1 list instead of everything, you can never delete a list. If
>   you don’t send the XML of the particular list, it is not updated.
>
> For deleting/destroying the Global list you need to create a special
>   XML package that you can send to the **SendUpdatePackge** method of
>   the **WorkItemStore** object. Sample code as below:

```
   string globalListName = "Test Global List";

   XmlElement returnElement;
   XmlDocument root = new XmlDocument();

   //Create a package element
    XmlElement newChild = root.CreateElement("Package");
    root.AppendChild(newChild);

   //Create a Destroy Global List element
  XmlElement element2 = root.CreateElement("DestroyGlobalList");
  element2.SetAttribute("ListName", "*" + globalListName);
  element2.SetAttribute("ForceDelete", true.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
  newChild.AppendChild(element2);

  //Send Update to Work Item Store
  store.SendUpdatePackage(newChild, out returnElement, false);
```

More details please refer this blog: [Deleting (or destroying) a Global List with the TFS API](https://roadtoalm.com/2013/01/09/deleting-or-destroying-a-global-list-with-the-tfs-api/)

Comment: @Patric-MSFT i did see the url already. but there is no such function SendUpdatePackage in ExtendedClient API. any idea?

Comment: @Rezoan please see the comments in the above [blog link](https://roadtoalm.com/2013/01/09/deleting-or-destroying-a-global-list-with-the-tfs-api/). Give a try with  https://onedrive.live.com/?id=61E84EB408BAD04%21920&cid=061E84EB408BAD04

Comment: Did see it. May be they are using some kinda custom library but not sure. Looking forward for any official resource. anyway i am currently using witadmin command via Process and able to destroy the globallist. thanks for your effort. appreciate it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InternalAdmin.DestroyGlobalList()` method to delete global list.

> public static void DestroyGlobalList(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore store, string globalListName, bool force)
>
> Member of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.InternalAdmin
>
> Summary: Destroys the passed in Global list.
>
> Parameters: store:  force: Destroy the lists even if they are in use.
>   globalListNames:

Code for your reference:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://xxx:8080/tfs/CollectionName/";
            string GlobalListName = "ListName";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(url));
            WorkItemStore wis = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            InternalAdmin.DestroyGlobalList(wis, GlobalListName, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try to use it and let you know.

Comment: @Rezoan No problem, let me know if you have any issue with it. :)